# Counting DE records based on a specific field

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

Can we check DE count based on specific field in same DE?

For Example :
`If Date= today()`

```ampscript
If DE_Count > 1 
              set @Subject= "hello"
else
              set @Subject = "Thank You"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) in combination with [RowCount](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/rowcount.htm), like this:

```
set @today = Format(Now(),"yyyy-MM-dd")
set @rows = LookupRows("DataExtension","Date", @today)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 1 then
set @Subject= "Hello"
else
set @Subject = "Thank You"
endif
```